# Is there a way to automatically restart docker after updating firewall rules with iptables?

Tags: iptables, systemd, docker

A recent update of iptables and firewall rules caused errors in our app. The culprit was finally found: the docker daemon needed to be restarted because it adds its own NAT rules to the firewall.

How can we automatically restart the docker daemon after adjusting firewall rules?

Comment: I think the answer to this relies in large part on how you adjust your firewall rules. Would you consider a wrapper script around iptables (which restarts docker either indiscriminately or somehow intelligently)? Or do you need to monitor the iptables ruleset for the relevant NAT rules and restart docker when they disappear?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Jeff Schaller's answer, we have a `start_iptables.sh` file that is essentially a one-time operation that configures the iptables rules. We persist the rules using `iptables-persistent save` and only run the file when making changes. At the end of the we restart our Docker stack since the Docker containers all exited.

```
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
echo "Restarting Docker stack..."
bash /path/to/start-docker-stack
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
```